# SQL - How do I join multiple tables and add appropriately with SUM?

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, sum, union

I'm trying to join multiple tables (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v.18.9.1) together (based on an ID) and have it SUM out a new column using a sum aggregate.  Here are my tables:

Table: **California**

| CaliforniaID | Name | AmountCalifornia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Alan | 1.00 |
| C1 | Alan | 1.00 |
| C1 | Alan | 1.00 |
| C1 | Alan | 2.00 |
| C2 | Eric | 2.00 |
| C2 | Eric | 2.00 |
| C2 | Eric | 3.00 |
| C3 | Janero | 3.00 |
| C3 | Janero | 3.00 |
| C3 | Janero | 5.00 |

Table: **Texas**

| TexasID | Name | AmountTexas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T2 | Eric | 2.01 |
| T2 | Eric | 2.01 |
| T2 | Eric | 2.01 |
| T3 | Jan | 3.01 |
| T3 | Jan | 3.01 |
| T4 | Lil | 4.01 |

Table: **Florida**

| FloridaID | Name | AmountFlorida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F5 | Manny | 10.00 |
| F5 | Manny | 10.00 |
| F6 | Nina | 11.00 |
| F3 | Jan | 100.00 |
| F4 | Lily | 27.00 |

Table **Junction1** that I created to be able to Join any tables that I need to in the future

All of the respective IDs match, so that I have something to join by

| CaliforniaID | TexasID | FloridaID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | T1 | F1 | Alan B. |
| C2 | T2 | F2 | Eric D. |
| C3 | T3 | F3 | Janero T. |
| C4 | T4 | F4 | Lila E. |
| C5 | T5 | F5 | Manuello R. |
| C6 | T6 | F6 | Nina H. |
| C7 | T7 | F7 | Perry R. |
| C8 | T8 | F8 | Ramos T. |
| C9 | T9 | F9 | Skye F. |
| C10 | T10 | F10 | Trinity A. |

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    j.name, 
    COALESCE(SUM(t.amount1), 0) AS CaliforniaExpenses, 
    COALESCE(SUM(t.amount2), 0) AS TexasExpenses,    
    COALESCE(SUM(t.amount1), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(t.amount2), 0) AS TotalExpenses
FROM
    junction1 j
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         CaliforniaID, null AS TexasID, 
         AmountCalifornia AS amount1, null AS amount2 
     FROM
         test1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         null, TexasID, null, AmountTexas 
     FROM
         test2) t ON t.CaliforniaID = j.CaliforniaID 
                     OR t.TexasID = j.TexasID 
GROUP BY
    j.name 
ORDER BY 
    CaliforniaExpenses DESC;
```

**Result**

| Name | CaliforniaExpenses | TexasExpenses | TotalExpenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Janero T. | 11.00 | 6.02 | 17.02 |
| Eric D. | 7.00 | 6.03 | 13.03 |
| Alan B. | 5.00 | 0.00 | 5.00 |
| Trinity A. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Skye F. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Ramos T. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Perry R. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Nina H. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Manuello R. | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Lila E. | 0.00 | 33.06 | 33.06 |

Which is great so far!  Is there any possible way to sneak in the `Florida` column `FloridaExpenses` (right after the TexasExpenses Alias) and have the total reflected for it as well?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Aggregate each State's Expenses table to ID level.

Step 2. Left outer join from Junction1 to the other three on ID column

```
with 
cte_ca as (select CaliforniaID, sum(AmountCalifornia) as AmountCalifornia from California group by CaliforniaID),
cte_tx as (select TexasID, sum(AmountTexas) as AmountTexas from Texas group by TexasID),
cte_fl as (select FloridaID, sum(AmountFlorida) as AmountFlorida from Florida group by FloridaID)
select j.Name,
       coalesce(sum(ca.AmountCalifornia),0) as CaliforniaExpenses,
       coalesce(sum(tx.AmountTexas),0) as TexasExpenses,
       coalesce(sum(fl.AmountFlorida),0) as FloridaExpenses,
       coalesce(sum(ca.AmountCalifornia),0)  + coalesce(sum(tx.AmountTexas),0) + coalesce(sum(fl.AmountFlorida),0) as TotalExpenses
  from Junction1 j
  left
  join cte_ca ca on j.CaliforniaID = ca.CaliforniaID
  left
  join cte_tx tx on j.TexasID = tx.TexasID
  left
  join cte_fl fl on j.FloridaID = fl.FloridaID
 group by j.name
 order by j.name;
```

Outcome:

```
Name       |CaliforniaExpenses|TexasExpenses|FloridaExpenses|TotalExpenses|
-----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
Alan B.    |            5.0000|       0.0000|         0.0000|       5.0000|
Eric D.    |            7.0000|       6.0300|         0.0000|      13.0300|
Janero T.  |           11.0000|       6.0200|       100.0000|     117.0200|
Lila E.    |            0.0000|       4.0100|        27.0000|      31.0100|
Manuello R.|            0.0000|       0.0000|        20.0000|      20.0000|
Nina H.    |            0.0000|       0.0000|        11.0000|      11.0000|
Perry R.   |            0.0000|       0.0000|         0.0000|       0.0000|
Ramos T.   |            0.0000|       0.0000|         0.0000|       0.0000|
Skye F.    |            0.0000|       0.0000|         0.0000|       0.0000|
Trinity A. |            0.0000|       0.0000|         0.0000|       0.0000|
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/36x7hAOa)